# shell script to delete certain files and rename others

Tags: shell

Currently I've a lot of .mp4 files with these names:

```
103160626309temp1ep10.mp4
103160626309temp1ep10.mp4.mp4

148999555452temp1ep6.mp4
148999555452temp1ep6.mp4.mp4

6802547045temp1ep5.mp4
6802547045temp1ep5.mp4.mp4

335587012366temp1ep4.mp4
335587012366temp1ep4.mp4.mp4
...
```

I must delete all files with single .mp4 and rename .mp4.mp4 to .mp4. Do you have an idea about how can I do it?

I think about using:

```
for i in ./*.mp4; do
...
```

and

```
for i in ./*.mp4.mp4; do
...
```

But I'm afraid and I can't lose the files or damage them.

Can you help me solve this issue?
Thank you.

Comment: http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashPitfalls#for_f_in_.24.28ls_.2A.mp3.29

Comment: It was just a example, I didn't tried because I'm afraid removing wrong files, btw, I'll update the question

Comment: You could just move them to another directory instead of deleting them. If you use `mv -b` it is quite save. And for renaming take a look at `man rename` that should (if your system uses perl-rename) have a `-n` option to have a look at what would happen first.

Comment: How can I move .mp4.mp4 files to another directory? because .mp4.mp4 is <file name.mp4>.mp4, not a extension.

Comment: I must do it using shellscript because I've a lot of files

Comment: `*.mp4` matches `file.mp4.mp4`. I would use something like `mkdir to_be_deleted; find -iname '*.mp4' -not -iname '*.mp4.mp4' -exec mv -b '{}' to_be_deleted \;`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need a separate deletion step if you just rename the `.mp4.mp4` files over the `.mp4` files.

(This assumes that for every `.mp4` file there is a corresponding `.mp4.mp4` file. If that is not the case, see the "multiple steps" instructions below.)

There are several ways to do that:

- Plain shell:

  ```
  for file in *.mp4.mp4; do
      mv -- "$file" "${file%.mp4}"
  done
  ```

  (Use `echo` instead of `mv` to see what it's going to do before you run it "for real".)
- If you have the perl version of `rename` (sometimes also known as `prename` or `perl-rename`):

  ```
  rename -f 's/\.mp4\.mp4\z/.mp4/' *.mp4.mp4
  ```

  (Use `rename -n` for a dry run.)
- If you have the util-linux version of `rename`:

  ```
  rename .mp4.mp4 .mp4 *.mp4.mp4
  ```

  Beware; this will simply replace the first occurrence of `.mp4.mp4` in the filenames, but hopefully that'll always be at the end of the filename.

  (Again, use `rename -n` for a dry run.)
- If you have `mmv`:

  ```
  mmv -d '*.mp4.mp4' '#1.mp4'
  ```

---

If you want to do things in multiple steps:

1. Create a separate directory for the files you want to keep:

   ```
   mkdir to-be-kept
   ```
2. Move all `.mp4.mp4` files into that directory:

   ```
   mv *.mp4.mp4 to-be-kept/
   ```
3. Delete all remaining `.mp4` files (or move them somewhere else if you want):

   ```
   rm *.mp4
   ```

   Or move them somewhere else:

   ```
   mv *.mp4 some/other/directory
   ```
4. Move the `.mp4.mp4` files back:

   ```
   mv to-be-kept/* .
   rmdir to-be-kept
   ```
5. Use one of the above recipes to do the renaming.

   You don't need `rename -f` (use plain `rename` instead) or `mmv -d` (use plain `mmv` instead) because in this case there's no need to overwrite existing files.

Comment: Only missing is `zmv` from `zsh` : `zmv -fW '*.mp4.mp4' '*.mp4'`

Comment: Hey, `rename -f 's/\.mp4\.mp4\z/.mp4/' *.mp4.mp4` worked perfectly! But I want run this command inside all folders and subfolders, so I'm trying use `find . -iname "*.mp4.mp4" -exec rename -f 's/\.mp4\.mp4\z/.mp4/' *.mp4.mp4 \;` and I'm getting this error a lot of times: `Can't rename *.mp4.mp4 *.mp4: No such file or directory`. Do you know how can I solve this issue?